# What can i add to balance this logo? (it's a band logo from PT)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo

[image]

Recently designed this logo for my band, it looks unbalanced to me.
Do you have any suggestions?

It's not a font, all hand drawn.

Comment: Its skewed to the lower right so put more in upper left.

Comment: pura mobkeys? is that what its supposed to say?

Comment: I find it more difficult to read than unbalanced... :-/

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft does not have an explanation in english, the band already had the name when i got in to it!

Comment: ah ok! what do they play?

Comment: @DigitalLightcraft i'm also part of the band, as a dj.
We are a kind of Electronic Funk/Soul band.

Comment: https://soundcloud.com/puramobkeys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just suggestions... based upon *my opinion*....

Reducing the size of the S goes a long way for balance...

[image]

Combine the reduction of the S and then shift the R to connect with the K rather then a b.... and I think it's much more balanced.

<sub>quickly painted and *far* from perfect.</sub>

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help! i'll let you know about the final result!

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a simple/clean geometric shape as a border or parallel lines.

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly extend the bottom of the M down to be level with the bottom of the Y and S.

I think this would balance it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the first character (P) needs to be made a little bit bigger. Perhaps lengthen the stem to make it relatively taller.

That should help to balance out the low-hanging 'S' on the end too.

Maybe it's just me but it seems like that 'P' could also be kerned over to the left slightly as well...

Looks pretty good overall though!

Comment: Thank mate! manual kerning on hand drawn "fonts" iits hard ahah! i'll work harder on it though!

Comment: No problem. Yes kerning is an art unto itself... Here is a site where you can practice if you're so inclined: [KernType](http://type.method.ac) Cheers